# “named-let” bug?

Tags: let-binding, recursion

The following code seems fine semantically:

```lisp
;; -*- lexical-binding: nil; -*-
(named-let f ((_ '(1)))
  (dolist (paren-1-paren _)
    (f ())))
```

Why does it throw an error?

(Is this a bug?
If so, I will report it.)

---

Reported as [bug#64290](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=64290).

Comment: @Drew: This question *essentially* has nothing to do with \[list\]; I'm just using it as an example.  You can try this: `(named-let f ((n 1)) (dotimes (i n) (f 0)))`. |||| So I removed tag\[list\].

Comment: You're right. Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(cl)Function Bindings`:

> -- Macro: cl-labels (bindings...) forms...
> The ‘cl-labels’ form is like ‘cl-flet’, except that the function
> bindings can be recursive.  The scoping is lexical, but **you can
> only capture functions in closures if ‘lexical-binding’ is ‘t’.**
> *Note (elisp)Closures::, and *note (elisp)Using Lexical Binding::.

Which is relevant because your code expands to:

```el
(funcall
 (cl-labels
     ((f
       (_)
       (dolist
           (paren-1-paren _)
         (f nil))))
   #'f)
 '(1))
```

And ultimately:

```el
(funcall
 (let
     (--cl-f--)
   (setq --cl-f--
         #'(lambda
             (_)
             (let
                 ((--dolist-tail-- _)
                  paren-1-paren)
               (while --dolist-tail--
                 (setq paren-1-paren
                       (car --dolist-tail--))
                 (funcall --cl-f-- nil)
                 (setq --dolist-tail--
                       (cdr --dolist-tail--))))))
   --cl-f--)
 '(1))
```

In which we can see specifically where that error would occur in the absence of lexical binding.

As the recursive call seems like a *standard* property of `named-let` I suggest you raise a documentation bug to suggest that it should indicate the `lexical-binding` requirement (which is maybe *implicitly* present in the existing reference to Scheme -- but only if you know something about Scheme).